# How to output a mysql query in Talend without executing it

Tags: java, sql, talend

I am new to TalendOS/DI. I'd like to export a mysql query as a .sql file without executing it.
So far, I am able to read data from an xml, write new entries into database, catch debug with a tJavaRow to get the global QUERY.

```
System.out.println((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlOutput_1_QUERY"));
```

But how to prevent physical access to database ?

Comment: Without a valid connection, the component will throw an exception before it set the tMysqlOutput_1_QUERY variable. You could substract the logic of the component to create your own "tMySQLQuery" component...

Comment: I have to agree with AxelH. I don't see how it can be done unless you create a custom component based on tMySqlOutput and strip away the part where it actually writes the data.

Comment: @iMezouar, how do I extend tMysqlOutput ? That would be great. I haven't seen yet relevant materials for custom code

Comment: @NavalonaRamanantoanina, you'll have to read up on component creation first and then copy what you need from the existing tMySQLQuery component. Here's a couple of links that might help: https://intodata.eu/talend-open-studio-how-to-create-a-custom-component-part-1/, http://www.powerupbi.com/talend/componentCreation_1.html. It's a bit of a road to go down on but if you're using Talend frequently it can be very empowering as well.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good way to start.